# ¿Cómo saber si el valor de una consulta a mysql es "NULL"?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo una consulta a una tabla en donde estoy pasando argumentos y el resultado de esta es que me devuelve todos los items almacenados que cumplan con los parámetros

```
public function obtenerSimilares($cod, $cat){
    $db = new Connection();
    $query = "SELECT nombre, cantidad, codigo, id_cat FROM articulo WHERE codigo <> '$cod' AND id_cat = '$cat'";
    $res = $db->query($query);
    $datos = [];
    // condicional
}
```

Hasta el momento tengo la siguiente condición la cual me sirve para conocer si tengo una sola tupla de resultado o varias para poder grabarlas.

```
if ($res->num_rows > 1) {
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $datos[] = [
            'codigo' => $row['codigo'],
            'nombre' => $row['nombre'],            
            'id_cat' => $row['id_cat'],
        ];
    }
} else {
    $datos[] = $res->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Va a haber ocasiones en que no se cumpla el `$cat` y el `$cod` (la variable cat es el identificador de la categoría y el cod es el identificador del código del artículo) y por lo tanto obtenga un null de respuesta pero el problema es que tengo un contenedor en donde voy a mostrar los resultados, solo que este contenedor tiene un `display: none;` en su css y es la razón por la cual quiero implementar una condicional que me diga si el resultado es un null para al momento de leer el script yo mantener el `display` con el valor determinado o en caso contrario cambiarle a `display: block`. He pensado en otra opción que consiste en dejar que el contenedor tenga un `display: block;` a cada instante y no controlar cuando el resultado de la consulta sea `NULL`.

**Nota:** mediante la api `fetch()` estoy leyendo el contenido de `$datos` y como es un array en los `.then()` definidos le hago parse para que tenga el formato JSON para que se facilite el recorrerlo y mostrar el contenido de cada objeto.

```
.then(res =>  res.json())
   .then(dataS => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(dataS));
```

Aquí deseo implementar `document.getElementById('contenedor').style.display ="block";`
o en otro caso crear en css una clase que tenga el `display: block;` para agregarla a la lista de clase del contenedor con `document.querySelector('.contenedor').classList.add('visible');`

**¿De que manera detecto en php si el resultado de la consulta es `NULL`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado de la consulta no puede ser `null`, las dos únicas posibilidades son:

1. Recurso de acceso a resultados que debes leer con algún método `fetch()`
2. Falso cuando hubo error en la consulta

Supongo que a lo que realmente te refieres es saber que la consulta no devolvió resultados y no deberías preocuparte por eso, basta con que definas un arreglo y llenarlo con la información obtenida:

```
// Inicializar el arreglo
$datos = [];
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Llenar arreglo con datos de la consulta, uno o muchos
    $datos[] = [
        'codigo' => $row['codigo'],
        'nombre' => $row['nombre'],            
        'id_cat' => $row['id_cat'],
    ];
}
// Enviar datos (vacío, uno o muchos) al navegador
echo json_encode($datos);
```

Finalmente, en Javascript compruebas la cantidad de filas recibidas:

```
.then(res =>  res.json())
.then(dataS => {
    if(dataS.length == 0) {
        console.log('No se encontraron resultados.');
    } else {
        // Sí hay resultados, puedes recorrer
        dataS.forEach(row => {
            // Va a mostrar las propiedades de cada fila:
            // codigo, nombre y id_cat
            console.log(row);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, intente simplemente poniendo un ``console.log(dataS.length)`` y este fue el resultado: Array(1)0: nulllength: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: @SantiagoBarreiro, la salida debería ser solo un número, probablemente estás enviando otros datos a la consola. En todo caso, por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/520561/edit) para poner el código actualizado, incluyendo la respuesta que envías desde PHP y cómo la interpretas en Javascript.

Comment: hace un rato volví a reiniciar los programas (XAMPP, Visual Code y cerre la ventana del navegador donde tenía abierto el proyecto) y ya visualizaba en consola que tenia un length de 0 y ya pude hacer lo de la parte del if que me indicaste, gracias por tu apoyo.